# Python/Pandas: How to Merge Data Frames and Reshape to Long Form?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I have data in dataframes of the kind (names of columns and values are dummies):

```
frame1 =            
           AA        BB
Date_Time                    
2001       1         5
2002       2         6
2017       3         7
2018       4         8

frame2 = 
           AA        BB
Date_Time                    
2001       10         50
2002       20         60
2017       30         70
2018       40         80
```

I would like to merge and reshape them into a long form dataframe, to be visualized with `seaborn`. Like this:

```
frame = 
        stn origin   value
Date
2001    AA  f1      1   
            f2      10
        BB  f1      5   
            f2      50
 ...
 ...
 2018   AA  f1      4   
            f2      40
        BB  f1      8   
            f2      80
```

How can I do that? I don't have any code to show because the couple of half-hearted attempts I made went nowhere close what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [Ravishankar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604520/4518857) pointed me in the right direction. With some searching I found (almost) how to do it, using `concat` with group keys and double stacking:

```
foo = pds.concat(dict(f1 = frame1, f2 = frame2), axis=1)

foo.stack().stack()

Date         
2001       AA  f1    1
               f2    10
           BB  f1    5
               f2    50
2002       AA  f1    2
               f2    20
           BB  f1    6
               f2    60
```

However, this method will produce a series with multi-index, which is not appropriate in all situations.
To create a dataframe with a single index (years), the following can be used:

```
bar = foo.stack().stack().reset_index(level=[1,2]).
```

Then the columns can be renamed according to need.

Comment: For future users that might have your same problem it would be better if you accept your own answer. The merging suggested in the other answer clearly does not accomplish what you were looking for

Comment: I have to wait until the system will allow me to do so, in two days.

Answer (score 1):

pd.concat should work to get the data frames merged. Can't comprehend Reshaping with the data samples

```
merged_df = pd.concat([frame1,frame2])
```

Comment: My problem is not about how to concatenate the dataframes, but how to reshape the result. In particular, I'd like to have a column to indicate the dataframe of origin of the value (because the're the result of elaborations with different parameters).